# override default font using @font-face

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

We want to modify default font in HTML using @font-face

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Times;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('serif');
}
```

in the above code we want to override Times font to serif, but above code is not working and Times font is getting used all the time instead of serif

Comment: Have you tried putting `Times` in quotes? Ex -- `font-family: "Times";`

Comment: @ChristopherBennett yes, tried

Comment: Maybe it just doesn't like "serif". Have you tried using a named font like `Marlett` (should come out as symbols), or `Impact` (will be very bold), to test?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett yes i just tried as you suggested, but still not working, it will be very helpful if you can provide snippet which works

Comment: Different browsers can have different default fonts. What's the end result you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this example, it works for me -- https://jsfiddle.net/gbk4rLw3/16/. However,  it doesn't seem to work if you try to switch a font with a generic font type such as serif or sans-serif, but any other web-safe font seems to work.

Test code is here as well.

HTML

```
<div class="test">
TESTING
</div>
```

CSS

```
.test{
  font-family: Times;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Times;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local("Impact"); /* Try replacing with Arial, Comic Sans MS, etc....*/
    }                          /*Doesn't seem to work with generic font types (serif,                                     sans-serif)*/
```

If you want a serif font, try using "Courier New".

Comment: thanks for your effort, i really appreciate it, do you have any clue why is does not work with generic font type?